# Footer content not floating to right

Tags: html, css

I have a footer with content in it. Problem I'm having is the content is displaying vertically instead of horizontally.

I've tried using float:right; that hasn't changed anything. Would really appreciate some help. 
Also two of the three social icons aren't showing up. That might be because of the float issue though...

Here's my code

```
<div class="footer-grid">
    <h3>More</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="footer-grid">
    <h3>Connect With Us</h3>
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li>
            <a class="facebook" href="#"> </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="pinterest" href="#"> </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="twitter" href="#"> </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="copy-right">Website by <a href="#">Elevate design</a></p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.footer-grid {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #414141;
}
.footer-grid:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.footer-grid h3 {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'arial';
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}
.footer-grid ul li {}
.footer-grid ul li a {
    color: #8C8C8C;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.footer-grid ul li a:hover {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
}
.social-icons li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.social-icons li a {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    display: block;
}
.social-icons li a.facebook {
    background: url(../images/facebook_icon.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
.social-icons li a.twitter {
    background: url(../images/twitter_.png) no-repeat -56px 0px;
}
.social-icons li a.pinterest {
    background: url(../images/pinterest.png) no-repeat -112px 0px;
}
.footer-grid p {
    color: #A2A2A2;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0 0.4em 0;
}
.footer-grid input[type="text"] {
    width: 84%;
    margin: 0.4em 0 1em;
    padding: 0.8em;
    border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
    transition: border-color 0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.5s all;
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.5s all;
    -o-transition: border-color 0.5s all;
    font-family: 'open_sanssemibold';
    color: #3D3D3D;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
    -o-border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.footer-grid input[type="text"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.footer-grid input[type="submit"] {
    background: #F36EA7;
    padding: 0.8em;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'arial';
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.3em;
    -o-border-radius: 0.3em;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.footer-grid input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #EE639F;
}
.footer-grids {
    padding: 3em 0 5em;
}
.copy-right {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.copy-right a {
    color: #A2A2A2;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.copy-right a:hover {
    color: #F36EA7;
}
```

Comment: are the `<h3>` tags supposed to be a similar color as the background? you can barely see them

Comment: No Sorry I was going to make them white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to put display:inline-block in .footer-grid ul li

```
 .footer-grid ul li{
       display:inline-block;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Silly mistake I guess.That's fixed it a bit, as in they are now horizontal but still stuck to the left side. Oh and when I float right they just move to the right hand of the screen. Unorganized is what I'm saying I guess haha.

Comment: Is there a way to upload images? I have a drawing. Sorry still new here.

Comment: you can upload images in your question

Comment: i added text-align:center; and width:31%; to the same class to get that fiddle

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add an image :(  Yeah that's more like it. I've added the image to imgur to clarify what I mean. http://i.imgur.com/uEcDNWI.jpg?1 Oh I'll email it to you :)

Comment: there's address in your footer?

Comment: Sorry, yeah the address is supposed to be a header and then have links beneath them. I deleted them out of frustration and forgot to re-add them... Like the footer here where it has legal and then links beneath it. Sorry not legal, technology rather...

Comment: That's nearly perfect!! Say I want the footer to scale to 20% of the page how would I achieve that?

Comment: just saw your comment now, will do a fiddle now

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Comment: can you mark my answer as accepted by hovering bside the answer and clicking the tick? it will turn green. hope i've helped you out :)

Comment: Thank you very much! when i tried that code it changed the width but that's my fault I didn't say height but I took what you did and changed it to height. The content seems to be a little messy now though: http://i.imgur.com/RBxHWHA.jpg

Comment: I changed them to a ul and it fixed most of it. Just gotta get the social icons over to the right now. I'll figure it out myself. Thanks very much @rachel-gallen

Comment: Wow you just keep giving!! Thanks very much! I have more than i expected so I'm going to stop you there before you end up doing the whole site for me haha. Thanks again! Wish I could give you something like reddit gold for stack exchange :)

Comment: haha! y'know you're beter off just puting the style from footer grid into footer and removing the footer grid classes. it will probably work better then

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try :)

Comment: Stop it! You're doing too much XD

Comment: Just one last thing the h3 more is off screen mostly. Any idea why?

Comment: i see what you mean you mean at the top - it's higher than the other heading? well you can adjust the margin-top hang on

Comment: If I have anymore questions would you mind if I mailed you? Thanks again, you've been a great help!

Comment: post them and tag me with the '@' symbol like @RachelGallen here's one for you type of thing. or you can mail me the link

Comment: I keep forgetting to do that. Cool thank you! Anyway of to the leaba with me.